# python_stubs directory placed in wrong location (PyCharm 3.4)

Tags: directory, default, pycharm

my current Win7 environment has the user home set to a network drive. Because of that PyCharm startup is taking a long time. Therefore I changed idea.properties to these values:

```
idea.config.path=c:/config/.PyCharm30/config
idea.system.path=c:/config/.PyCharm30/system
```

All is working fine and startup is much faster now. But a background process is rebuilding the skeleton files (which takes a long time) and is placing them here:

```
<myNetworkDrive>:\.PyCharm30\system\python_stubs\-1234567890\
```

It seems that this skeleton process doesn't follow the settings in idea.properties. Or is there any other setting I have to make?

Thanks, 
Best regards,
Michael

I copied and adapted this from here because it is unanswered, thanks to Marcel for that question:
http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1971

Comment: Have you tried to invalidate (File->Invalidate Caches/Restart) caches after making changes to `idea.properties` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the write way. I've changed file config/options/jdk.table.xml.
It worked for me.

I've changed line

```
<root type="simple" url="file://$USER_HOME$/.PyCharm30/system/python_stubs/1167955305" />
```

to

```
<root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/system/python_stubs/1167955305" />
```